# Distance matrix batch process for different area types in one layer

Tags: qgis, distance-matrix

I have a layer of the centroids of all neighbourhoods in a city, with neighbourhood ID and borough ID as attributes of each point. The city is made from boroughs, which are themselves made from neighbourhoods. I want to create a distance matrix between all neighbourhoods within each borough, but there are so many boroughs that selecting each and finding the distance matrix would take a long time. Is there a way to run this as a batch process? The batch process option seems to act between different layers.